# Wildcard in preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, wildcard

I have a form.
I want when users fill the form with these content for example:

```
Word (in Spain)
```

or

```
Word2 (in England)
```

Automatically (in *) removed and saved in database like this:

```
Word1
```

or

```
Word2
```

I used this code:

```
$obj['String'] = trim(preg_replace( '(in /\(.*)\/)', '', $obj['String'] ));
```

but this code not working and my table in database filled blank.

Comment: `(` and `)` are reserved characters in regex. You're escaping the wrong ones. You're also forgetting your modifiers (the characters at the start and end - most of the time `/` is used). `preg_replace('/\(in .*\)/', '', $obj['String']`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: you want to say "You're also forgetting your" delimiters.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Of course - I'm mixing up delimiters and modifiers (they're actually ones that come *after* the delimiters specifying whether it's an in-case-sensitive search, multiline, DOTALL etc.)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Thanks for your help. but still saved with `(in *)`. This is my code now: `$obj['String'] = trim(preg_replace('/\(in .*\)/', '', $obj['String'] ));`

Comment: @Kasra What do you mean with "still saved with"?

Comment: @h2ooooooo for example `Word (in Spain)` had been saved in my table in database (Sorry for my English).

Comment: @Kasra So you want to replace whats already in the database table?

Comment: @h2ooooooo No. Its a new row. Currently I am using your code, But when the user enters the data in form, the data stored in the database is unchanged.

Comment: @Kasra [I cannot confirm](https://eval.in/155695).

Comment: @h2ooooooo Sorry man, It was my bad. In fact, the capital letters in `in` made the problem... Sorry again and thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kasra If you add the `i` modifier to your regex then it's in-case-sensitive: `/\(in .*\)/i` (and will replace `IN`, `in`, `In` and `iN`)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Wow, Thanks man, now everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't escaping the right characters, have a try with:

```
$obj['String'] = preg_replace( '/\s*\(in .*\)\s*$/', '', $obj['String'] );
```